# I found my factual answer but the question is closed as "opinion based." How to open?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, specific-answer

I saw what appeared to be an obvious similarity between the Star Trek "Mycelial Network" and Cosmic strings [so I posted a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220586/are-cosmic-strings-the-creators-inspiration-for-st-discoverys-mycelial-networ). A couple people assumed the answer didn't exist and closed it.

[An interview with the main Mycelial network actor Anthony Rapp](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/star-trek-discovery-anthony-rapp-wilson-cruz-interview-hugh-culber-returns-1186393) confirmed the connection between the fungus and the way the universe works:

> He was in this crazy mycelial land and had this moment in the network to help bridge the gap initially. But the real consequences didn't come until this season, and I'm so glad it got to come full circle. There's an opportunity to really explore loss and peer into the abyss of the unknown. **Plus it's grounded in some real science with how energy transforms and moves throughout the universe.** The writers have found a way to do it that resonates and is really satisfying to play.

Also the connection is found in *The Science of Star Trek: Discovery's Mycelial Network* connecting quantum astrophysics mathematical equations (string theory) with biochemistry (fungal mycelium):

> the ideas behind the spore drive came from the research of Dr. Paul Stamets (Anthony Rapp), who, along with his research partner, **chose to think of physics and biology as interchangeable at the quantum level**. Through this thinking, and **generating equations based in quantum astrophysics and biochemistry, the two were able to theorize** that, as Star Trek wiki Memory Alpha says, “spores were not only the progenitors of panspermia, but also the building blocks of energy across the universe,” and thus something starships could theoretically use to travel.

The answer is FACTUAL and the answer is YES.

[image: Cosmic String Network]

These mathematical equations in quantum astrophysics were the inspiration for the Star Trek Discovery's unique propulsion system.

Please open the question for the community so these facts can be posted.

Comment: If the question was assumed to have been inviting discussion, it was likely to be closed as opinion-based.  However, closing it for "nobody has any answer and it won't be found" has always been wrong, and something we need to re-teach every so often.

Comment: I am at a loss on how to get this factual SciFi information posted for fans to find. The closed question is a real roadblock, I can't duplicate the question, and I can't answer the question. Information death.

Comment: Note that you have a quote from an actor, who learned of this after the fact, that says he believes it's related to some real science, though he doesn't say what.  Which may be entirely post-facto rationalization of treknobabble.

Comment: That's ridiculous. It certainly disproves "there is no answer" notion. Omnitience now?

Comment: @VogonPoet - well, you can start by being less dramatic, and learning a bit more about how the site you seem to want to be part of works.  Editing the question now unfortunately will not help it - if it was merely on hold, doing so would automatically enter it for a reopen vote.  Now that it is fully closed due to age, it won't.  I have just submitted a first reopen vote - that ought to put it in the review queue for other votes to be cast.  Hopefully, you have enough people you haven't irritated beyond reason to assist in the effort.  Good luck.

Comment: UPDATE: It now only needs one more re-open vote to be opened...

Comment: there's nothing in the article you cite above that references string theory though. If the question was "is the ST:D network based on science", then yes. Based on string theory: no.  http://twincitiesgeek.com/2018/04/the-science-of-star-trek-discoverys-mycelial-network/

Comment: That has to ignore the fact that quantum astrophysics *is* string theory. Occasionally concepts bear different names, and in theoretical physics there are MANY mathematical attempts to explain panspermia. Strings are the common element. A good answer makes that undeniable connection.

Comment: @VogonPoet What you're saying doesn't make any sense. String theory is an attempt to quantize gravity, it's not related to astrophysics per se. There's no such thing as quantum astrophysics, even if astrophysics itself uses quantum mechanics. Panspermia is a theory where life in the universe is propagated via asteroids/comets from one solar system to the next. Theoretical physics has nothing to do with the latter. Also, cosmic strings and strings from string theory are totally different beasts. The former are topological defects from GUTs while the latter are 1D objects that model particles.

Comment: That is just not true, as you just pointed out "Grand Unified Theory" is not simply an attempt to quantize gravity. It is an attempt to give one mathematical model of hadrons, baryons, and space-time which accounts for everything we know. MANY different models exist - all predict the existence of "strings" which help explain the distribution of mass into superclusters, as well as [provide conduits for panspermia](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2173553_Kolmogorov_Complexity_String_Information_Panspermia_and_the_Fermi_Paradox). ST Mycelium does exactly this.

Comment: @VogonPoet You really have no clue what you're talking about, I give up. Cheers!

Comment: Greatly appreciated. It'll all make sense in time

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you could edit your question so the meta bits about "I don't know how this is opinion-based" are taken out, and it focuses on the question? As it is, your original question is kind of lost in a pseudo-rant.

Also, you could respond to the comments there and provide some more reasoning behind why you think there is a connection. Your quotes in the above meta-question should help. Then, at least, you will have a reasonably good quality question.

However, your quotes do not specifically mention cosmic strings - just an assertion by an actor that it is "grounded in some real science with how energy transforms and moves throughout the universe" - so they don't quite qualify as an answer.

Comment: The question's been edited as per your suggestion.