# Are post deletions always undeclared?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

My post was deleted within 40 minutes of being posted, no comments or indications as to why. If there is a reason for deleting content, would it be wise to let the poster know what (if anything) they did wrong? Otherwise, it seems that the proper course of action would be to simply put the post up again (because there is nothing objectively wrong with it).

Are deleted posts completely undeclared, or is there some way of knowing why it happened?

I am led to believe votes to close an answer have certain criteria, which my post obviously does not meet:

> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

I refer to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222421/120362) which meets NONE of the deletion criteria in even the wildest possible abstraction.

Comment: Don’t misrepresent the situation. One of the delete voters commented on why it wasn’t really an answer to the question. I wasn’t going to add unnecessary fluff just to reiterate the point made.

Comment: well, for my part, being one of the deleters in question, I commented prior to deleting. I stated that it was an exact dupliate of another answer (item #4). Additionally, the rest of the answer was an attempt at humor in the vein of Adams, which isn't necessary to the answer or helpful, thus it also met #1 and #6 when I came back later after an edit that didn't really modify it substantially, and voted to delete

Comment: Don't worry, I will represent everything correctly. Are you saying "*The rest is little better than Vogon poetry*" is a comment on "why it wasn't really an answer?" Really?? It's a pedantic and useless remark.

Comment: The part that is not a duplicate appears to be an unsupported personal theory.

Comment: I was meeting Adams-esque humor with Adams-esque humor. I do sincerely apologize that it was taken as a hurtful attack.

Comment: There are six reasons listed in the question, all from the SFF help center. Can you help me understand which one of those "apparent unsupported personal theory" falls into? My support is actually in the links.

Comment: @NKCampbell - I got the humor and appreciated it. It was not yourself that opinied your joke was in fact a "comment on why it wasn’t really an answer"

Comment: I get that. Seems like the intent is "keep these people in good favor or else?"

Comment: @NKCampbell - What concerns me is that you voted to close an answer that you didn't even understand. Your last comment was "how can it be a gimmick for Restaurant when..." My research answered that question on the 7th line.

Comment: "*it seems that the proper course of action would be to simply put the post up again*" - No, it really doesn't

Comment: Why not? If the content is appropriate, and no one is suggesting (legitimately) that is isn't, it needs to be reposted.

Comment: I can understand that line of thinking - however, note that I didn't vote to delete when I first read it and commented. I voted to delete about 30mn later after the addition of the Restaurant bit at the and (which i think you added to make your point more clear, which is a good thing) but *mainly* because it had reach -4 or -5 by that point thus it seemed like an appropriate candidate for deletion. Additionally, I don't have the power to delete with one vote. That power lies with users far exceeding my rep.

Comment: @NKCampbell one vote deletion is a mod only power.

Comment: I'm confused. You state that you will "represent everything correctly", but when the original poster of the close comment chimed in with their version of the comment, *we can clearly see your version omits the first sentence, which indeed does provide a close reason*. For as long as I have been on SE, duplicate answers have been removed, as they offer no real value. If we did allow them, we could open up the door to all sorts of duplicate low quality answers that just reiterate previous users answers. We **don't** want that.

Comment: @NKCampbell - As I suspected. I knew that you both 1) did not read the post and 2) voted based on score. Nothing against you, you openly said that's how you save time. [It proves a flaw in the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334771/why-not-reward-blind-voting), which I am addressing.

Comment: I posted this comment below - but I'll add it here as well in response - ...I think I see what Vogon is saying - in that the answer wasn't intended to be largely humerous or nonsensical but a serious attempt at an answer. In which case, I a) can respect that - that's what we're here for after all b) perhaps it was simply poorly written (not an attack!) such that at least 5 users and 3 voters were unable to determine it's intent. In that case, feel free to re-post another try at something more coherent

Comment: in other words,to sum up: I did read the post, it made no sense, I thought it was a joke / duplicate. Commented as such. Waited. More people downvoted as well. Edit made, no significant change. More downvotes. Voted to delete per site standards. Sorry if that hurt your feelings or felt like a personal attack. It wasn't. Feel free to try the answer again

Comment: ...ehh....but you didn't give credit to the original answer :)

Comment: To quote Gimili: "I asked for but one hair from her golden head.....she gave me three" :D alright, I've made my case. Repost or not. Have a good day :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - The third comment says my answer is "an exact duplicate" of something. Seriously, I can't find any question resembling what I wrote. A comment like that is helpful to have some sort of link? A simple "share link" gets the job done?

Comment: no no - the duplicate part of your answer duplicates the accepted answer

Comment: If you want to give credit to an answer, reposting the same answer is a no no. If you want to give credit, you can select the up arrow above the answers score. This will upvoted the users answer, and reward them with some reputation.

Comment: Why do I keep coming in here expecting to see something different from this ongoing mary sue drama..

Answer (score 10):

One of the delete voters explained their reasoning in a comment for why it wasn’t really an answer and the part that was, was just duplicating information already in the answers.

> the part of this that is an answer is a duplicate of the other highly voted and accepted answer. The rest is little better than Vogon poetry

For my part this reiterated my thoughts so I wasn’t going to leave a near identical comment explaining why it wasn’t needed. The latter half of the comment might have not been great but I think you understood what they meant even if it could have been clearer. Though I think given the context the comment isn’t too bad.

To answer the general question here though, deletions don’t have to be accompanied with a reason. Most of the time, if it’s not just spam, R/A or a troll, a user will leave a comment for why they are voting to delete. As was the case here.

Comment: OK, this explains it well. Since there appears to be no reason for deletion within the six defined reasons given by SFF-SE, the appropriate action is just to repost the useful content. That seems a bit of a waste of time, however. Maybe we have better uses for our time?

Comment: I'm confused @VogonPoet ...do you feel the answer should meet all 6 criteria to be deleted?

Comment: @VogonPoet it’s been explained why at least two of the users felt it warranted deletion. One even married it up to three of your quotes points. If you’re not going to actually read and take in the feedback I don’t see the point for this meta question other than to drum up drama.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - What you call reasons simply are not, on this site. Hence this question was needed. Killing a post in 40 minutes is called "drumming up drama" given how targeted the activity is (anyone can look through the questions and see how often and quickly closes are made).

Comment: @VogonPoet - Posting something that's 20% dupe, 80% nonsense is going to get your answer deleted **whoever you are**.

Comment: @VogonPoet on top of what Valorum said, can you stop this victimisation stuff? It helps _nothing_ and you have no evidence it happens. People are not necessarily voting because it’s you but the content as has been said repeatedly to yourself.

Comment: ...I think I see what Vogon is saying - in that the answer wasn't intended to be largely humerous or nonsensical but a serious attempt at an answer. In which case, I a) can respect that - that's what we're here for after all b) perhaps it was simply poorly written (not an attack!) such that at least 5 users and 3 voters were unable to determine it's intent. In that case, feel free to re-post another try at something more coherent :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Valorum and Skooba provided the evidence. [A score reflects the author's popularity](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12783/120362), not content quality. More exactly, "there might some adjustments you can make in your own attitude that can help your questions be better received" and "engage with downvoters with humility, you'd turn those downvotes into upvotes." That's almost **10 combined years experience saying author unpopularity decreases a score**. I call that substantiated.

Comment: @VogonPoet no score and votes reflect the posts quality. Those quotes are saying if you actually listen to feedback given, take it in and edit accordingly you’re content might then be better received. It’s not saying if you’re likeable your content will always get lots of upvotes.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot -  I believe you believe that. Objectively a sample of low scoring posts very clearly says differently. Reaching -5 then deletion within 40 minutes is quite an elite club, survivors should get a badge! Try it on Data Explorer.

Comment: You can of course also complain as long on meta about people being mean until they *actually* start voting down your posts just for being tired of it and make your self-fulfilling prophecy come true. That's not a particularly fruitful endeavour, but then you would at least have a reason to continue wasting your time with complaints and the "fun" can go on till foreverevermore.

Comment: Thank you to whomever voted to reopen, I'll postpone the repost.

Comment: @VogonPoet- as to why one question may get attention and another one won't, for my part anyway, look at my history and you'll see that I mostly only answer / read Star Wars/Trek, Potter, and Lotr questions

Comment: @VogonPoet That’s not a good post by any stretch of the imagination but it is an answer in some form and does give credit. It’s also worth noting it depends when and who sees your post. For my part I saw your post in the low quality posts review queue so someone else had already flagged it.

Comment: @VogonPoet _"I'll postpone the repost."_: reposting is fine but please don't repost the _exact_ same answer, take the feedback on board and edit it accordingly. In fact if you edit the current answer accordingly I'd be happy to review it and undelete if I felt it warranted it.

Answer (score -3):

Ignoring all the commentary on whether this was a targeted attack, and whether users have to explain their votes, I don't think the answer warranted deletion. From the comments to the answer and the comments here I gather that the two principal issues that people had with the answer were that it duplicated content from another answer, and that (the rest of) it was an unsupported theory.

Regarding the first point, I don't think that is an issue here. The answer was clearly not attempting to give the same answer as a previous answer; rather that information provided context for the (different) direction that this answer was taking, namely looking somewhere other than the author for an explanation of the cover art.

As for the second part, I freely admit that I do not have enough familiarity with this particular work to know if the theory presented has any merit to it. However, deletion is generally reserved for answers that either don't address the question at all, or are incomprehensible, rude, or spam. As this answer does not seem to be any of those, I don't think deletion is warranted. If users believe that it is not a *good* answer, downvotes are definitely justified.

Based on the above I have voted to undelete the answer.